# C# NHibernate StaleObjectStateException

Tags: c#, hibernate, exception

I have a MySQL database linked with NHibernate. 
I am getting a `StaleObjectStateException`:

> Message : Test method DALTest.UnitTest1.AddingResultAndGetAll threw
>   exception:  NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or
>   deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was
>   incorrect): [Domain.Bean.Result#3]

...here on the rr.Save call :

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
rr = new ResultRepository();
FootRace foot = new FootRace(2,"une courseeee", "vraiment une chouette course", date, 5, false);
Participant part = new Participant(2,"Boveeé", "Joseeé", 123, "M", date, 5);

rr.Save(new Result(3,foot,part , new TimeSpan(2500),5));
```

Where my Interface implementation is :

```
public void Save(Result result) {
                var e =Session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntityEntries;
                Session.SaveOrUpdate(result);
                Session.Flush();
            }
```

After doing some research it looks like it's a thread problem but I can't find a solution to this. By the way the database is resetted at the moment i call this test, so there is absolutely nothing inside.

---

Here is the XML mapping file:

```
<class name="Result" table="result">
    <id name="Id" column="idResult" type="int">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="FootRace" class="FootRace" column="idFootRace" cascade="save-update"/>
    <many-to-one name="Participant" class ="Participant" column ="idParticipant" cascade="save-update"/>
    <property name="RaceTime" column="raceTime" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="Rank" column="rank"/>
</class>
```

Comment: I forgot the xml mapping file :
`<class name="Result" table="result">
    <id name="Id" column="idResult" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="FootRace" class="FootRace" column="idFootRace" cascade="save-update"/>
    <many-to-one name="Participant" class ="Participant"  column ="idParticipant" cascade="save-update"/>
    <property name="RaceTime" column="raceTime" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="Rank" column="rank"/>

  </class>`

Comment: edit your question and add the mapping

Comment: Fixed up code tags, and added in the XML mapping file from the comments.

Comment: @e_i_pi thanks for editing (and correcting) my post !

Comment: Are you using identity columns in your database? I understand that the `foot` object and `part` doesn't exists and you want to create all 3 objects, right?